# Jquery Popup plugin closes when clicked anywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, magnific-popup

When I click anywhere on the popup it closes, but its not supposed to do that, it supposed to close only when I click on the X button. Im using Magnific Popup Plugin.  The author's demo works fine, but when I implement the plugin on my site, it doesn't work like the demo. This is causing problems for me because If I try to click on any link in the popup, it closes the popup instead of opening the link.

Any ideas what's causing it? Code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.simple-ajax-popup-align-top').magnificPopup({
          type: 'ajax',
          alignTop: true,
          overflowY: 'scroll' // as we know that popup content is tall we set scroll overflow by default to avoid jump
        });

        $('.simple-ajax-popup').magnificPopup({
          type: 'ajax'
        });

      });
    </script>

<a class="simple-ajax-popup-align-top ajax-gal"  href="test.html">test</a>
```

Author's Demo Site: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

Comment: jsfiddle or at least the content that is loaded into the lightbox

Comment: It looks like there's an option called `closeOnContentClick` that **should** be false by default, but it describes the behavior you're seeing. Maybe try explicitly setting it to be false?

Comment: Check zIndexes of the elements the popup create and see if you have any element layered on top (z-axis) of them that may be interfering on click events

Comment: I just added jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bgbs/VNfdC/ but I'm not sure how to add the ajax-test.html locally so that it loads in the box, right now it does not load the file in ajax because it can't load remote files

Answer (score 0):

There are several options which control closing behaviour.

```
closeOnContentClick: false, // if true, closes the popup if you click on it
closeOnBgClick: true, // if true, closes the popup if you click on the grey stuff around it
showCloseBtn: false, //if true, shows a closing button top right.
```

You can learn more about these options here: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#options

Since you are a lazy programmer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.simple-ajax-popup-align-top').magnificPopup({
      type: 'ajax',
      alignTop: true,
      closeOnContentClick: false,
      closeOnBgClick: true,
      showCloseBtn: false,
      overflowY: 'scroll' // as we know that popup content is tall we set scroll overflow by default to avoid jump
    });

    $('.simple-ajax-popup').magnificPopup({
      type: 'ajax',
      closeOnContentClick: false,
      closeOnBgClick: true,
      showCloseBtn: false
    });

  });
</script>
```